# jquery works on jsfiddle, but not on my website

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

***Here is the link to the jsfiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/d3xMZ/

when I hover, it does exactly what it is suppose to do, which is load the social sharing.
but when I implemented it on my website, nothing happens on hover.
Can anyone help, I have googgled and looked at similar questions on stackoverflow, but no luck

Comment: Quick checklist: are you using another toolkit? did you check the console for errors? are you sure your all your scripts are loaded? did you check for mark-up errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Include the jquery library on your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Next, Wrap the jquery code inside

```
$(function() {
  //place the js part here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to call it when the page loads, (so it can make sure the elements exist):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Your code here...
});
```